# MySQL syntax error near "from (subquery) 'table'"

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

```
select *
from ( select * from table ) 'table1';
```

I cannot see why I am getting this error:

**ERROR 1064 (42000):** `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''table1'' at line 2`

I have checked the manual ([MySQL subquery in FROM clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html)) and I can't see any difference between the examples and my little statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Table names/aliases must either be surrounded with backticks or nothing

```
select *
from ( select * from table1 ) table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want back quotes rather than forward quotes:

```
select *
from ( select * from table ) `table1`;
```

Forward quotes specify a string constant.  Back quotes delimit a name.

Answer (score 0):

when you have a subquery that is a table, you need to declare it with a name.

```
select * from (select * from table1) as x
```

Comment: not quite true. OP is doing it, but using single quotes which makes the alias a string, not an alias/field/table name.

Answer (score 0):

As well as not putting quotes around the alias, I believe you also need backticks around "table" in the subquery because it's a reserved word in MySQL (assuming you did actually name your table "table"):

`` select * from ( select * from `table` ) table1; ``